# How to disconnect bluetooth to an iOS device from an Android app programmatically

Tags: kotlin, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I tried using BluetoothSocket.close() but it doesnt work. It only works when I disconnect to an Android device. When I try to disconnect to an iOS device, the Bluetooth Socket is closed, but the bluetooth connection still persists- still connected.

Here's how I establish the connection

```
    fun connectDevice(device: BluetoothDevice) {
        bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
        if (device.bondState != BluetoothDeviceInfo.BondState.PAIRED.value) {
            device.createBond()
        } else {
            val uuids = bluetoothAdapter?.getRemoteDevice(device.address)?.uuids
            uuids?.let {
                var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null
                bluetoothJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    for (uuid in it) {
                        try {
                            val convertedUUID = uuid.uuid
                            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(convertedUUID)
                            socket?.connect()
                            bluetoothSocket = socket
                            break
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            LogUtils.d(e.message.toString())
                            socket?.close()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's how I disconnect the connection

```
        bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                bluetoothJob?.cancel()
                delay(1000L)
                bluetoothSocket?.let {
                    it.outputStream.close()
                    it.inputStream.close()
                }
                delay(1000L)
                bluetoothSocket?.close()
                bluetoothSocket = null
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                LogUtils.d(e.message.toString())
            }
        }
```

I have tried these possible solution but still doesn't work.

- Wrap the bluetooth connection inside a coroutine Job and then cancel it before closing the bluetooth socket
- Closing the outputStream and inputStream before closing the bluetooth socket
- Adding delays between processing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For debugging purposes you can [enable BTSnoop logs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-logs) on your Android device and see at HCI level what goes wrong when you disconnect from your iOS device.